# how can to add classes on a single <li> during an event in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm new in meteor framework and I try to create a project that every time I clicked on the name on a single `<li>` the background should change to yellow. And if I click another `<li>` the previous one should go back to it's original color and the next `<li>` should turn to yellow.

So I try to add .selected class on that using the unique id from MongoDb. By comparing the id's using if statement, but it's not working.

Here is the code:

body.html:

```
<body>
    <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
    {{> leaderboard}}
</body>

<template name="leaderboard">
<ul>
    {{#each player}}
        <li class="player {{selectedClass}}">{{name}}: {{score}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

body.js:

```
 import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';
 import './body.html';
 import {PlayersList} from '../api/players.js';

    Template.leaderboard.helpers({
            'player': function(){
                return PlayersList.find();
            },
            'selectedClass': function(){
                var playerId = this._id;
                var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
                if(playerId == selectedPlayer){
                    return "selected"
                }
            }  
        });

    Template.leaderboard.events({
        'click .player': function(){
            var playerId = this._id;
            Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
        }
    });
```

main.css

```
.selected{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making a few changes to your Template. I've added them here with some annotation.

leaderboard.html

(note that we are now passing in `_id` to the helper)

```
<template name="leaderboard">
  <ul>
    {{#each player}}
      <li class="player {{selectedClass _id}}">{{name}}: {{score}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

leaderboard.js

```
import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';
import {Tracker} from 'meteor/tracker'; // import Tracker here
import './body.html';
import {PlayersList} from '../api/players.js';

Template.leaderboard.onCreated(function() {
  // subscribe to your publication in the onCreated lifecycle call
  // to ensure the playerList is available for the component
  // http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe
  this.subscribe('<publication-name>');
});

Template.leaderboard.helpers({
  'player': function(){
    return PlayersList.find();
  },

  // pass in data to helper
  // http://blazejs.org/guide/reusable-components.html#Pass-data-into-helpers
  'selectedClass': function(playerId) {
    // use Session.equals here - fewer invalidations are triggered
    // https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html
    return Session.equals('selectedPlayer', playerId)
      ? 'selected' : '';
  }  
});

Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click .player': function() {
        var playerId = this._id;
        Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
    }
});
```

The key takeaway is to know what `this` is within your helpers and event maps.

Comment: @makopa_fruit does this help clear up the issue or are you still having problems? Considering my answer has been down-voted I'd like to know if this worked for you.

Comment: @chazsolo sir this works like a charm, can i know what is it called? is it publication? the template you added.
and im sorry i cant upvote your answer. my account is new. dont have privilege to upvote anyone.

Comment: @makopa_fruit If this answer solved your problem, you can _accept_ it.

Comment: @makopa_fruit not likely the publication/subscription as you already had data on the page (can only assume you haven't removed the `autopublish` package). As stated in my answer, you were more than likely not successful in setting the session value correctly because of your data contexts. Did you ever console.log what `this` is in your helpers/events? If it wasn't what you were expecting (the data context of each player) then that would be the reason.